# How to find the area of triangle ABC?

Tags: geometry, triangles

How to find the area of triangle ABC if BP is an angle bisector?

[image]

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Angle_Bisector_Theorem

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! Your question is stated as an isolated problem without context and doesn't show any effort of your own. Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3986511/edit) your question to improve it. As of now it is likely to attract down votes and get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$AB=x;\;BC=y$$
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{x}{1} =\frac{y}{2}\to y=2x\\
x^2+y^2=9\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$x^2+(2x)^2=9$$
$$x=\frac{3}{\sqrt 5};\;y=\frac{6}{\sqrt{5}}$$
$$Area=\frac{1}{2}xy=\frac{9}{5}$$

Comment: Thank you so much